# Is there a more async or lazy vc-mode?

Tags: vc

### Question

Does a "lazy" or "asynchronous" vc mode exist?

### Background

Emacs `vc` mode is designed on the assumption that the version control backend is fast. Much of the core vc features wants the version control status information immediately. For example, `vc-refresh-state` is run from `find-file-hooks`, which sets up buffer local state with respect to the `vc` backend, *synchronously*.

There are places that do issue commands asynchronously. E.g. I do see `vc-do-async-command`, and it is called for some operations, just not the ones that matter most to me (e.g. from `find-file-hooks`).

### My negative experience

This is a problem on slow file systems or if the version control system is not fast. For example, with `global-auto-revert-mode` on, in a large Mercurial client, where any given `hg status` takes 0.3 seconds, changing the current branch can take quite a long time if I have a lot of buffers open.

If I disable vc mode with something like `vc-ignore-dir-regexp` I lose all vc commands. I would gladly give up small niceties like up-to-date version control information in the mode line, if it got me performance.

### Lazy approach

A "lazy" vc mode might delay all interaction with the version control system until the user explicitly interacts with a vc command. Commands such as `vc-diff` would first determine the vc backend, if needed, and then do the operation. This would be functional equivalent of having no vc mode at all, and simply switching to a shell and running commands like `foo diff`, except that it would still have the nice Emacs veneer. In some respects, this might end up being a "vc mode lite".

### Asynchronous approach

An "asynchronous" vc mode would be more delicate to design and implement, but essentially run all external commands on an asynchronous queue. This way, a large number of files could be auto reverted without blocking Emacs.

Comment: For mercurial repositories i made [vc backend](https://github.com/muffinmad/emacs-vc-hgcmd) that uses hg command server. It's much faster to communicate with persistent hg process rather then invoke hg on every command. It's not answer your question but it may speed up you work with mercurial repos.

Comment: Interesting. And if on a unix-ish system, https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CHg may be useful too.